# Stuck of defining the Covariance of two random variables

Tags: statistics

So I'm having some troubles when it comes to defining the Covariance of two random variables **X** and **Y**.

The assignment says:

If **cov(X, Y)=1** find **cov(2X+1, Y)**

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you know any properties of covariance that might be useful in this situation?

Answer (score 1):

Covariance is a billinear operator, which satisfies the properties that I have listed below. Let $X, Y, $ and $Z$ be random variables, and let $a, b$ be real numbers. Then,

- $\text{cov}(X, a) = 0$
- $\text{cov}(X, X) = \text{var}(X)$
- $\text{cov}(X, Y) = \text{cov}(Y, X)$
- $\text{cov}(aX, bY) = ab \cdot \text{cov}(X, Y)$
- $\text{cov}(X, Y + Z) = \text{cov}(X, Y) + \text{cov}(X, Z)$
- $\text{cov}(X + a, Y + b) = \text{cov}(X, Y)$

These can be derived from the definition of $\text{cov}(X, Y)$.

---

Using these properties, we can work backwards and write

$$\text{cov}(2X + 1, Y) = 2 \cdot \text{cov}(X + 1/2, Y) = 2 \cdot \text{cov}(X,Y) = \boxed{2}$$